# download large file using streams from nodeJs to angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, node-streams

i am struggling to get this stream downloading file works
if i try the same request using curl the stream works fine and streaming the data.
in my angular app the file is completely download before the client see the download file tab it seems like the subscribe only happened after all stream body fully downloaded

what i am trying to achive is after first chunk of data send to angular app
i want the file to start downloading.

instead after observing the network only after all file downloaded from the backend
the downLoadFile methood is called and the ui expirence is stuck

this is a minimal example of what i am trying todo
at the backend i have a genrator that genreate a huge file
and pipe the request

**Node JS**

```
const FILE = './HUGE_FILE.csv'

const lines = await fs.readFileSync(FILE, 'utf8').split('\n')

function* generator() {
    for (const i of files) {
        console.log(i)
        yield i
    }
}
app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=\"' + 'download-' + Date.now() + '.csv\"');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    res.setHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    const readable = Readable.from(generator());
    readable.pipe(res);
});
```

at the client side calling the endpoint and waiting for the resonse

**Angular code**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'is-optimizer-csv',
    templateUrl: './optimizer-csv.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./optimizer-csv.component.scss']
})
export class OptimizerCsvComponent implements OnInit {

    private onDownloadButtonClicked() {
        const data = {...this.form.get('download').value, ...(this.advertiserId ? {advertiserId: this.advertiserId} : null)};
        this.loading$.next(true);
        this.optimizerService
            .downloadOptimizerCsvData(data)
            .pipe(
                take(1),
                tap(_ => this.loading$.next(false))
            )
            .subscribe();
    }

  
}





@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OptimizerService {
    constructor(private readonly http: Ht, private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

    downloadOptimizerCsvData(data: any) {
        this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}`,{
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',headers:headers} 
           ).subscribe(response => this.downLoadFile(response, "text/csv"));
  
      }
      downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
        let blob = new Blob([data], { type: type});
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let pwa = window.open(url);
        if (!pwa || pwa.closed || typeof pwa.closed == 'undefined') {
            alert( 'Please disable your Pop-up blocker and try again.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the part where you label it Angular code from the service or the consumer component?  Can you share the component .ts file code relevant to download flow?

Comment: thanks for response  just update my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it look like angular common http client does not support streaming out of the box .

see this github issue by @prabh-62

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44143

from this thread the why to solve your issue is by implementing the fetch stream logic using native `fetch`